# MyModel.findOne is not a function when using Mongoose in Next.js 14 Middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have the following call in my Next.js middleware:

```
let user: UserType[] | null = null;

    try {
        user = await findUser({id});
        console.log("user", user);
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
    ⨯ unhandledRejection: Error: TypeError: ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.User.find is not a function
    at addSiteToIntegration (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./middleware.ts:51:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here is my Mongoose schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    apiKeys: [
        {
            purpose: String,
            key: String,
            allowedOrigins: Array,
        },
    ],
    customerRating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    businessName: String,
    businessRating: Number,
    bio: String,
    businessBio: String,
    businessDisplayName: String,
    isBetaUser: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    reviewWizardPresets: [
        {
            id: String,
            text: String,
            onStars: String,
        },
    ],
    blockList: [
        {
            type: String,
        },
    ],
    accesingWebsites: [{ url: String, description: String, name: String }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: () => Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
});

export default mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This issue only apppears in Next.js middleware not in regular Server Components or Route Handlers. Any idea why?

I'm using Next.js 14.1, Mongoose 8.2.0, and MongoDB 6.0.13 pn my Atlas cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `middleware` in Next.js is an [Edge Function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/middleware#runtime) where there are limitations, as the [Edge Runtime in Next.js is based on Web APIs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/edge). So connecting to a database does not work most of the time.

And speaking of `mongoose`, you definitely cannot, as they say on their [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/nextjs.html):

> Mongoose does not currently support [Next.js Edge Runtime](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/edge-and-nodejs-runtimes#edge-runtime). While you can import Mongoose in Edge Runtime, you'll get [Mongoose's browser library](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html). There is no way for Mongoose to connect to MongoDB in Edge Runtime, because [Edge Runtime currently doesn't support Node.js `net` API](https://edge-runtime.vercel.app/features/available-apis#unsupported-apis), which is what the MongoDB Node Driver uses to connect to MongoDB.

You need an API endpoint somewhere, that connect to your database, that your middelware would call.

Comment: I'm not connecting in middleware. I have that in a whole seperate file for that.

Comment: But you are importing that file in the middleware, right ?